# Storing buttons to a variable

Tags: java, user-interface

So for my program i have three buttons;

- Button1: 8
- Button2: 5
- Button3: 3

---

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JButton b1= (JButton) e.getSource();
        JButton b2= (JButton) e.getSource();
        String button= b1.getText();
        String button2 = b2.getText();
        System.out.println("b1: " + button);
        System.out.println("b2: " + button2);
```

I'm trying to check which buttons are pressed and storing them into the variable. So when the user presses 8, button should be 8, and once they press any second button, button2 should get that button

Comment: I don't understand your confusion, you create two identical buttons in this code, and expect them to have different `getText()` values?

Comment: @Tyler sorry about the confusion basically im trying to store the buttons the user pressed

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, for better help sooner provide a [Minimal, **Complete** and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) The code provided until now, is not enough for us to provide more help than what @Tyler said...

Comment: Where does the output "Pressed 8:" come from? Could you provide that part of your code, too, please?

Comment: `JButton b1= (JButton) e.getSource();` and `JButton b2= (JButton) e.getSource();` will make `b1` and `b2` refer to the same JButton object, Isn't it?

Comment: @HarminderSingh Currently both your button refers to the same source (I.e the same button)

Comment: Seems XY problem, I feel illogical here. Try add characteristic data to every component by `putClientProperty()`, and read this in event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do i make a new ActionEvent?

Currently both your buttons refer to the same source (I.e the same button)

If the actions to be triggered are similar in nature (for example, the buttons in MineSweeper, they are different buttons, but the actions to be triggered are the same), then you don't have to create multiple action listeners for multiple buttons. You can let your buttons add the same action listener:

```
//Example
class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    private JButton btn1, btn2;

    public MyPanel(){
        btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        btn2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        ButtonHandler bn = new ButtonHandler();
        btn1.addActionListener(bh);
        btn2.addActionListener(bh);
    }
}
```

Infact, what you wanted to do is just a one-liner:

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println((JButton)e.getSource().getText());
    }
}
```

However, if you have different actions for different buttons (for example, `Start Game` and `Exit Game`), then you can create  separate action listeners for them.

Comment: but i need to store it because after i get the buttons im going to do something with it

Comment: @HarminderSingh You just want to keep track which button has been pressed and the order of the button pressed is not important right?

Comment: In that case you actually don't have to "remember" the order of the button pressed. Just invoke the respective methods immediately once you pressed any of the buttons. I don't think you are writing a program with "sticky-keys" where a series of button press will have different results such as `ctrl-C` & `ctrl-V` on the keyboard. I mean your  buttons are supposed to work as individual right?

Comment: ya they are individual

Comment: @HarminderSingh Take a look at my updated answer. It seems to me now you actually wanted different actions for your buttons (and not just printing their text). In that case, you create separate action listeners for them.

Comment: Im already doing that in my other class , im doing b1.addActionListener(mb1); same with b2 and b3, its just the buttons im having trouble with

Comment: @HarminderSingh Then it should be working. If it is not, it is probably caused by other issues. Actions from action listerners shall be executed once button is pressed. You hardly requires it to be stored with delayed actions unless you are making a game.

Comment: it works but what im trying to do is, if the first button is 8 and second button is 5, i do something for that and so on, im trying to use the buttons i got basically and so something with ti

Comment: @HarminderSingh You can easily achieve that with boolean flags. Just set the flag to true when the button is pressed. When pressing `5`, check the flag for `8` and see if it is already pressed. If every button's order is important, then you can create a new Button class which extends JButton and add an attribute such as `private boolean isPressed` so all buttons can remember their own states.

Comment: how do i check if the flag is 8 and by flag u mean boolean flag?

Comment: @HarminderSingh How do you check? Just assign and read from the same boolean variable. All the things I have to say is in my previous comment. Like I say, you can also create a new button class.

Answer (score 0):

So maybe you want to check the source of the event? Like:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == b1) {
        System.out.println("b1 pressed");
    } else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
        System.out.println("b2 pressed");
    } else {
        System.out.println("some other button pressed");
    }
}
```

and you should really create different buttons outside of the scope of this actionPerformed method!

**EDIT**
The example solution by user3437460 is much better than this one…

Comment: would this work because my buttons and actionPerformed are in different classes

Comment: You will need to refer to them somehow… You can implement different listeners for different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Every component can hold information on it, by putClientProperty(); 
This mechanism is kind of map, so can hold few named objects. We use only one.
This obcjet (pie of information) is not visible for user, it is not text written on button like `getText()` in few tries, is only for consuming by algorithm. There can live not only primitives or strings, but live objects too.

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    private JButton btn1, btn2;

    public MyPanel(){
        btn1 = new JButton("Button 1");
        btn1.putClientProperty("myinternalsense", 8); // <-- here

        btn2 = new JButton("Button 2");
        btn1.putClientProperty("myinternalsense", 5);  // <-- here
        btn1.putClientProperty("myfunctor", new MyFunctor() );  // <-- here

        ButtonHandler bn = new ButtonHandler();
        btn1.addActionListener(bh);
        btn2.addActionListener(bh);
    }
}
```

This information is accessible in any context, for example common event handler to many buttons.

```
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println((JButton)e.getSource().getClientPropertygetText("myinternasense"));  // <-- here
    }

}
```